# Signalr and servicestack

Tags: servicestack, signalr

I have a servicestack server app that only process api calls (rest).
I am trying to implement the functionality I found [in this Strathweb.com article](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/03/signalr-filters-and-servicestack/).

To call my api's I use the url .../api/getthis and it works well.

I added the IncomingHubAttribute and OutgoingHubAtttributes and decorate my methods with them and the methods get called and all is good.

I can browse to `localhost:1234/signalr/hubs` and I see the generated js **but when I browse to `localhost:1234/log.html` as described in the article I get 
**hub.client is not defined.****

I have the following in my apphost file...

```
//Switch ServiceStack’s mode of operation to buffered,
PreRequestFilters.Add((req, res) => req.UseBufferedStream = true);
...

public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
{ ...
RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
```

I have read about having to add

> SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig{RawHttpHandlers...

but don't fully understand what would get routed to where.  I feel I am so close.

This is my log.html file

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="messages"></ul>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts\jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts\jquery.signalR.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/signalr/hubs"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var hub = $.connection.servicelog;//<---- **this does not seem to get resolved**


            hub.client.log = function (data) {
                $('#messages').prepend('<li>' + data.Time + " - " + data.Data + '</li>');
            };

            hub.client.logMessage = function (data) {
                   $('#messages').prepend('<li>' + data.Time + " - " + data.Data.Id + " " + data.Data.Name + '</li>');
            };

            hub.client.logArray = function (data) {
                $('#messages').prepend('<li>' + data.Time + " - " + data.Data + '</li>');
            };

            $.connection.hub.start();
        });
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are loading an incorrect signalr script "Scripts\jquery.signalR.core.js". It should be "Scripts\jquery.signalR-(version).js"

Comment: That did it - Thanks SOOO much for the extra set of eyes.  I accepted your answer :)